# Handle pointer to member in templates while creating a simpler `bind` to use with asio

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I would like to create a wrapper to simplify writing the binds for the handlers, so that I just have to give the callback and a data pointer.

This is my code :

```
#include <utility>

template <typename Func, typename Data>
class Handler
{
   const Func & m_func;
   volatile Data & m_data;

public:
   Handler(const Func & f, Data & d) :
      m_func(f),
      m_data(d)
   {}

   Handler(const Handler & cpy) :
      m_func(cpy.m_func),
      m_data(cpy.m_data)
   {}

   template<typename Res=void, typename... Args>
   Res operator()(Args... args) const
   {
      return m_func(m_data, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
   }
};

/* I need help to handle this specialization */
template<typename T>
template<typename Res=void, typename... Args>
Res Handler<(T::*)(Args...), T*>::operator()(Args... args) const
{
   return (m_data->*m_func)(std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}


template <typename Func, typename Data>
inline Handler<Func, Data> handler(Func f, Data d)
{
   return Handler<Func, Data>(f, d);
}
```

The goal is to use it like this :

```
boost::asio::async_read(socket,
                        boost::asio::buffer(d, n),
                        handler(callback, session)
);
```

or like this :

```
boost::asio::async_read(socket,
                        boost::asio::buffer(d, n),
                        handler(&Object::method, this_ptr)
);
```

But I have problem handling the specialization for the latter case...

Comment: any reason not to simply use a lambda?

Comment: readability and I'd like to learn how to write such a template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to write your own template, there's a lot to fix in yours. First, you're keeping references to temporaries. Your `handler()` function needs to take references itself, or you need to keep values. Prefer to keep values. If the user wants to pass in references, they can always use `std::ref`. So let's start with that. Here's a simple handler with data:

```
template <typename Func, typename Data>
struct Handler
{
   Func func;  // NB: not a reference
   Data data;

   template<class... Args>
   auto operator()(Args&&... args) const  // NB: this wasn't a forwarding ref before
       -> decltype(func(data, std::forward<Args>(args)...))
   {
      return func(data, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
   }
};
```

Okay, so now we have an aggregate, which is already copyable and movable and all the good things we want without having to write it out ourselves (not that your `Handler` is movable - but moving it called the copy constructor...)

Now, we can write our function out:

```
template <class F, class D>
Handler<std::decay_t<F>, std::decay_t<D>> handler(F&& f, D&& d) {
    return {std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<D>(d)};
}
```

To handle member functions, you just need a separate overload of `handler`. Everything else remains the same, we'll just conditionally wrap pointers to members with `mem_fn`:

```
template <class R, class T>
auto handler(R T::* p, T* cls)
    -> Handler<decltype(std::mem_fn(p)), T*>
{
    return {std::mem_fn(p), cls};
}
```

Eh voila.

Answer (score 0):

c++11:

```
boost::asio::async_read(socket,
                        boost::asio::buffer(d, n),
                        [this](boost::system::error_code const& ec, std::size_t transferred)
                        { this->method(ec, transferred); });
```

c++14:

```
boost::asio::async_read(socket,
                        boost::asio::buffer(d, n),
                        [this](auto const& ec, auto transferred)
                        { this->method(ec, transferred); });
```

Lambdas are perfectly good asynchronous handlers in asio.

They also work with strands etc:

```
boost::asio::async_read(socket,
                        boost::asio::buffer(d, n),
                        this->strand_.wrap([this](auto const& ec, auto transferred)
                        { this->method(ec, transferred); }));
```

not to mention `shared_from_this()`...

```
boost::asio::async_read(socket,
                        boost::asio::buffer(d, n),
                        this->strand_.wrap([self = this->shared_from_this()]
                        (auto const& ec, auto transferred)
                        { self->method(ec, transferred); }));
```

Comment: ...I didn't asked how to do it with lambda, I did asked how to correct my template, since it's useful to know how to write such a template ;)

Comment: @hl037_ understood, I did a similar thing and then went back to lambdas. In the end they are more maintainable and easier to read and debug. Best of luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to just use a lambda:

```
boost::asio::async_read(socket,
    boost::asio::buffer(d, n),
    [&](boost::system::error_code const& ec, size_t transferred) {
        // either it's a free function
        return callback(session, ec, transferred);

        // or it's a member function
        return session.member(ec, transferred);
    }
);
```

---

The most generic with [`std::invoke()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke):

```
boost::asio::async_read(socket,
    boost::asio::buffer(d, n),
    [&](auto&&... args) -> decltype(std::invoke(callback, session, decltype(args)(args)...)) {
        return std::invoke(callback, session, decltype(args)(args)...);
    }
);
```

Or if you always know if the callback is a pointer to member function or not, you can just use the right one, whether:

```
[&](auto&&... args) -> decltype(callback(session, decltype(args)(args)...)) {
    return callback(session, decltype(args)(args)...);
}
```

or:

```
[&](auto&&... args) -> decltype(session.member(decltype(args)(args)...)) {
    return session.member(decltype(args)(args)...);
}
```

Comment: ...I didn't asked how to do it with lambda, I did asked how to correct my template, since it's useful to know how to write such a template ;)

Comment: @hl037_ Why do you want to write a 20 line template when you can write a 3 line lambda?

Comment: because `handler(callback, session)` is much faster to write and to understand than a 3 line lambda, while the 20 line template is just a tool that doesn't introduce overhead compared to a lambda

Comment: @hl037_ The lambda doesn't introduce overhead... Agree to strongly disagree on faster to understand.

Comment: yes, I meant the lambda doesn't introduce overhead and the template neither ;)